# How to add item to a list in angular 6?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add items to a list of objects as shown in my code.

It's about adding just the item but I'm getting an error about argument is not assignable to parameter of type...

Please have a look at my code to understand more about the issue !

```
 // item to add :
 item: SideBarMenu[]=[];
 // list in which I want to add my item: 
 subMenuItems=[{
 code: '1',
 defaultLabel: 'Home ',
 icon: 'home',
 routerLink: ['/'],
 fragment: 'home-anchor'
},
{
code: '2',
defaultLabel: 'Table',
icon: 'table',
routerLink: ['table_demo'],
fragment: 'search-anchor'
  },
 {
  code: '3',
  defaultLabel: 'Interval',
 icon: 'calendar',
 routerLink: ['interval_demo'],
 fragment: 'search-anchor'
},
{
code: '4',
defaultLabel: 'Check-Box & Radio button',
icon: 'check_box',
routerLink: ['check_box_demo'],
fragment: 'search-anchor'
 }

]

     this is my class : 
     export class SideBarMenu {
       public code: string;
       public defaultLabel: string;
       public subMenus?: SideBarMenu[] = [];
       public routerLink?: string[] = [];
       public icon?: string;
       public fragment?: string;
       }

 // function : 
 addnew(){
 this.subMenuItems.push(this.item);
 this.showDialog=false;
 this.item=new SideBarMenu();
 }

   //   html part : 
        <form class="form-horizontal" #f="ngForm">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 control-label">Code <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-4">
                            <input type="number" name="code" min='1' placeholder="Entrer le code" [(ngModel)]="item.code" required> 
                    </div>

                    <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 control-label">Icône </label>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-4">
                            <input type="text" name="icone"  [(ngModel)]="item.icon" > 
                    </div>

                    <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 control-label">Default Label <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-4">
                            <input type="text" name="defaultLabel" [(ngModel)]="item.defaultLabel" required> 
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 control-label">Fragment <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-4">
                            <input type="text" name="fragment" [(ngModel)]="item.fragment" required > 
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 control-label">RouterLink </label>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-4">
                            <input type="text" name="routerLink" [(ngModel)]="item.routerLink" > 
                    </div>
                  </div>


        </form>
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
    ERROR in src/app/sidebar-demo/sidebar-demo.component.ts(106,24): error 
    TS2345: Argument of type 'SideBarMenu[]' is not assignable to parameter 
   of type '{ code: string; defaultLabel: string; icon: string; routerLink: 
   string[]; fragment: string; }'.
   Property 'code' is missing in type 'SideBarMenu[]'.
   src/app/sidebar-demo/sidebar-demo.component.ts(108,1): error TS2322: Type 
   'SideBarMenu' is not assignable to type 'SideBarMenu[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type 'SideBarMenu'.
```

Help me please how to fix that ?

Comment: You are trying to assign a value to a property while the types do not match. A quick look seems to suggest you are trying to assign an array to an object. Please double check your code for such a case.

Comment: so how to fix that?

Comment: I don't know. Your code is a bit messy and seems to have several syntax errors. Please edit your question so it includes properly formatted and working code.